# Upgrading sql management studio 2008 r2 to 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms, upgrade

I have sql management studio (SSMS) 2008 R2 on my work station and I want to upgrade it to sql management studio 2012. How do I directly upgrade 2008 to 2012

Comment: That's nice. Good luck with that. Did you have a programming question?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d2SE46xaKYE

Comment: Actually, I do have some programming questions with sql server compression table. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Thanks, but this video mentioned is not talk about the local upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "Upgrade" SSMS, you just install the 2012 version. If you don't want the 2008 version anymore, you uninstall it. Otherwise you can have both on the same computer.

Comment: This is correct!! You can connect to both versions from your workstation.